# What is best method to check my game is not iframe loaded by 3rd party domain

Tags: javascript

What is the best method to security check that my JS game is not currently being embedded (iframe loaded) by some 3rd party trash domain?
  It seems content security policy does not always work.

Comment: Have you tried "jumping out" of the iframe by setting `window.parent.location.href=http://mygame.com` , or just checking if there is a `window.parent`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options